# PHP return only 0 in array_filter

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

I am trying to only return when the value in the array is only `0`. Because `array_filter` automatically filter `0`, `null`, `empty` etc I need to use custom callback.

But get every return that is not `null`, `empty`

the array is

```
[
    (int) 0 => '0',
    (int) 1 => '-100',
    (int) 2 => '100'
]

function countBETrades($arr) {
    $arrBE = array_filter($arr, function($v){
        return $v !== false && !is_null($v) && ($v != '' || $v == '0');
    });
    
    return count($arrBE);
}
```

Comment: yes but I am looking for the value `1` to be returned because there is only one `0`

Comment: It will filter nothing but `false` and `null` values because it will match `$v != ''`. Seems like you would want to replace that `||` with `&&`. But Berto99's answer is definitely more fitting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want only the number `0` to be counted, then you only need to check for it (using the triple `=` in order to force PHP to check the type, so `null === 0` is false):

```
function countBETrades($arr) {
    $arrBE = array_filter($arr, function($v){
        return $v === 0 || $v === '0';
    });
    
    return count($arrBE);
}
```